# Send email to new sign user using AWS sns with lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, serverless-framework

I am working on one project with AWS lambda function, DynamoDB, serverless architecture with the node.js runtime environment.

Now thing is that I want to send an email when a new user signup in my system for email address confirmation.

First, I tried with SES(SMTP credentials) and nodemailer module. When we try to send an email using SES then we need to verify both the email addresses(`From` and `TO`). But thing is that suppose I verify my `From` email address but the new signup user has a new email address, so, this when I try to send an email to the new signup user's email address then it through error like email address not verified.

So, i want to know that if I want to send an email to this new signup user how can I send the email confirmation mail?

Can I use SNS with AWS lambda and serverless architecture?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suspecting your Amazon SES is still in [sandbox mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html). As long as you are in sandbox mode, you can only do the following things:

- You can only send mail to verified email addresses and domains, or to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.
- You can send a maximum of 200 messages per 24-hour period.
- You can send a maximum of 1 message per second.

To get yourself removed out of sandbox mode, you need to open a [SES Sending Limits Increase case](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/) to the AWS Support center.

Comment: Hello @Thomas thanks for your answer. I just want to know that if I increase the limit then is affect into a coast?

Comment: do you think I can go ahead with the help of SNS service or else SNS is helpful in my case or not?

Comment: No, increasing the limit has no effect on your cost. The only impact on your cost would be if you send more emails

Comment: Combination of Lambda -> SNS -> SES is great for your scenario

Comment: Can you please share any working example for this combination? I want to use AWS Lambda + Serverless Architecture + SNS or SES(or both)